# How do I query mysqli db's with variables in a loop (php)

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, foreach

I'm learning a bit of php and mysqli and atm I'm trying to create a simple private messaging system. For that I created two tables I need, one for my site's users and one for the messaging. There is one connection between both tables atm and its the username (not the userid). I created a working php script that fetches a list of pms for the session user. For that I created a foreach loop that allows me to show every pm with the same recipients username like the session user in a form. My problem is that the pm table doesn't content the senders prename and name and that is what needs to be shown in the form instead on the username.

I already figured out that querying content from another table than pm isn't possible in the foreach loop but I can't get it to work anyways.
What I tried:

1. prepared statements with PDO to fetch them in a while loop inside the foreach loop -> whole form content not showing
2. Query and fetch like outside of the foreach (which does work btw.) -> whole form content not showing

Since I'm completely new to mysqli I have no idea what to try now. Can someone give me a hint?

"users" table columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `username` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `password` char(80) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup1` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup2` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `prename` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `rights` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

"pm" table columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sentby` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `recipient` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `new` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

pm.php (submit isn't set up yet)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script>
function onSelectChange(){
    document.getElementById('frm').submit();
};
</script>
 <?php
$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

//start session and define mysqli connection $conn
include 'header.php';

//query own private messages as session user
$sqlownpn = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE recipient='$username'";
$queryownpn = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlownpn);

echo "<h3>Inbox</h3><br>";

echo "<div id=“resp-table-body”>
        <form action='$phpself' id='frm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

            <select name='pn' id='pn' size='3' onchange='onSelectChange()'>";

function build_choice($rows2)
{  
    $result = "";
    foreach ($rows2 as $row2){
        $sentby = $row2['sentby'];
        $new = $row2['new'];
        if($new == 1) {
            $result.= "<option value='{$row2['id']}'>NEU | {$row2['timestamp']} | $sentby | {$row2['thema']} | {$row2['ueberschrift']}</option></div>";

        } elseif($new == 2) {
          $result.= "<option value='{$row2['id']}'>{$row2['timestamp']} | $sentby | {$row2['thema']} | {$row2['ueberschrift']}</option></div>";
        };
        return $result;
    };
};
  
echo build_choice($queryownpn);
echo "</select><br></form></div><br>";
?>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

This script is working. I just need to get the associated prename and name for the senders username (in the loop defined as $sentby). All pms are created by users existing inside users table.

Any ideas?

Comment: So where is `$username` created and given a value

Comment: _“There is one connection between both tables atm and its the username (not the userid).”_ - then that is the very first thing you should fix. Use the IDs for this, that’s what they are for. You do not want to go and change data across all message records, just because some user wants to change their _name_ at a later point. (And even if that is not a use case within your app, doesn’t matter - Use. The. IDs.)

Comment: _Small Point_ If's, Loops and function braces do not need the semi colon.. Like `};`

Comment: $username is created from the sessions username in header.php from '$_SESSION['username'];' I worked with username from day one and I am aware to work with userid instead in online projects. Just for me better to see.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with INNER JOIN added into the function:

```
global $conn;
$sqlnamelist = "SELECT a.id, a.prename, a.name, b.absender FROM users AS a INNER JOIN pm AS b ON a.id = b.sender";
$querynamelist = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlnamelist);
      while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querynamelist)) {
    $sender = $row4["sender"];
    $vorname = $row4["prename"];
    $nachname = $row4["name"];
    if($sentby == $sender) {
    $valid = "1";
    $name = "$prename $name";
    }
    else {
    continue;   
    }
```

Is that safe?